# What does the"unclean and clean" refer to in Deutoronomy 12:15?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, moses, sacrifice

Deutoronomy 12:15 NASB

> 15 “However, you may slaughter and eat meat within any of your gates, [g]whatever you desire, according to the blessing of the Lord your God which He has given you; the ***unclean and the clean*** may eat of it, as of the gazelle and the deer.

Does this unclean and clean refer to persons or the animals?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to an unclean person, other versions of the Bible expand and explain the verse. The word "**person**" in bold inserted in the verses by me

Deuteronomy 12:15  (AMP)

> 15 “However, you may slaughter and eat meat within any of your [city]
>   gates, whatever you wish, according to the blessing of the Lord your
>   God which He has given you [as His generous provision for daily life].
>   The [ceremonially] unclean **person** and the clean may eat it, such
>   as the gazelle and the deer."

Deuteronomy 12:15  (NIRV)

> 15 But you can kill your animals in any of your towns. You can eat as
>   much of the meat as you want to. You can eat it as if it were antelope
>   or deer meat. That is part of the blessing the Lord your God is giving
>   you. Those **persons** who are “clean” and those who are not can eat
>   it.

**What makes a person unclean?**

Leviticus 5:2-3  (NASB)

> 2 "Or if a person touches any unclean thing, whether a carcass of an
>   unclean beast or the carcass of unclean cattle or a carcass of unclean
>   swarming things, though it is hidden from him and he is unclean, then
>   he will be guilty."
>
> 3 "Or if he touches human uncleanness, of whatever sort his
>   uncleanness may be with which he becomes unclean, and it is hidden
>   from him, and then he comes to know it, he will be guilty."

Read also Leviticus 11:21-24 and  17:15 for ceremoniously unclean persons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question of what this is referring to is bound up in the **common** or **sacrificial** element of the flesh being killed and eaten as to what state of **cleanness** one must be in to eat the flesh in reference.
In all of Scripture regarding sacrifice only Pigeons, Cattle, Sheep and Goats are given for and in sacrifice, there is no provision for sacrificing deer, or as the KJV says it roebuck and hart. Deer are clean for eating commonly but not sacrificially thus Moses uses them as an example that

> "you may kill and eat flesh in all your gates, whatsoever thy soul
>   lusteth after... as the roebuck and hart"

Even the flesh of your Cattle and Sheep and Goats one could eat if they were being eaten commonly (for dinner) just as one would eat a deer (which is not a sacrificial type animal). 
According to Lev 7:20, this statement was assuring a person that they could eat a common piece of flesh regardless of it they were 'ceremonially' clean or unclean, no matter what they could still kill a Cow, Sheep or Goat for common dinner, but they couldn't eat a offering or vow unless they were clean:

> Lev 7:20  But the soul that eateth of the flesh of the sacrifice of
>   peace offerings, that pertain unto the LORD, having his uncleanness
>   upon him, even that soul shall be cut off from his people.  Lev 7:21 
>   Moreover the soul that shall touch any unclean thing, as the
>   uncleanness of man, or any unclean beast, or any abominable unclean
>   thing, and eat of the flesh of the sacrifice of peace offerings, which
>   pertain unto the LORD, even that soul shall be cut off from his
>   people.

Below is some further commentary on Deuteronomy chapter 12

In the context of what is spoken of in this chapter, it is referencing different forms of worship which YHWH deems as acceptably and that beside common food to be eaten. The Chapter stats with condemning the way the other nations worshiped and condemns their places of worship, both of which are contrasted with YHWH's commanded worship:

> Deu 12:2  Ye shall utterly destroy all the places, wherein the nations
>   which ye shall possess served their gods, upon the high mountains, and
>   upon the hills, and under every green tree...

**This is in reference to the way in which an animal was to be killed and prepared for sacrifice.
As the follow says :**

> Deu 12:4  Ye shall not do so unto the LORD / YHWH your God.  Deu_12:5 
>   But unto the place which the LORD your God shall choose out of all
>   your tribes to put his name there, even unto his habitation shall ye
>   seek, and thither thou shalt come:  This 'place' is a reference to the
>   tabernacle in the wilderness:
>
> > > Deu 12:6  And thither ye shall bring your burnt offerings, and your
> > >       sacrifices, and your tithes, and heave offerings of your hand, and
> > >       your vows, and your freewill offerings, and the firstlings of your
> > >       herds and of your flocks: Deu 12:7  And there ye shall eat before the
> > >       LORD your God, and ye shall rejoice in all that ye put your hand unto,
> > >       ye and your households, wherein the LORD thy God hath blessed thee. 
> > >       Deu 12:8  Ye shall not do after all the things that we do here this
> > >       day, every man whatsoever is right in his own eyes.  Deu 12:9  For ye
> > >       are not as yet come to the rest and to the inheritance, which the LORD
> > >       your God giveth you.

**Further the eating of specifically sanctified animals is mentioned:**

> > Deu 12:10  But when ye go over Jordan, and dwell in the land which the
> >     LORD your God giveth you to inherit, and when he giveth you rest from
> >     all your enemies round about, so that ye dwell in safety;  Deu 12:11 
> >     Then there shall be a **place** which the LORD your God shall choose to cause
> >     his name to dwell there; thither shall ye bring all that I command
> >     you; your burnt offerings, and your sacrifices, your tithes, and the
> >     heave offering of your hand, and all your choice vows which ye **vow**
> >     unto the LORD...

At the time this was spoken it was before the land was conquered, it is referring to the Tabernacle in the wilderness, yet the reference is to the moving of the 'place' as it would be the tabernacle in Shilo Jos 18:1 & Lev 17:9  and eventually Jerusalem 1Ch 22:1.

> Deu 12:11  Then there shall be a place which the LORD your God
>   shall choose to cause his name to dwell there; thither shall ye bring
>   all that I command you; your burnt offerings, and your sacrifices,
>   your tithes, and the heave offering of your hand, and all your choice
>   vows which ye vow unto the LORD:  Deu 12:12  And ye shall rejoice
>   before the LORD your God, ye, and your sons, and your daughters, and
>   your menservants, and your maidservants, and the Levite that is within
>   your gates; forasmuch as he hath no part nor inheritance with you. 
>   Deu 12:13  Take heed to thyself that thou offer not thy burnt
>   offerings in every place that thou seest:  Deu 12:14  But in the place
>   which the LORD shall choose in one of thy tribes, there thou shalt
>   offer thy burnt offerings, and there thou shalt do all that I command
>   thee.  Deu 12:15  Notwithstanding thou mayest kill and eat flesh in
>   all thy gates, whatsoever thy soul lusteth after, according to the
>   blessing of the LORD thy God which he hath given thee: the unclean and
>   the clean may eat thereof, as of the roebuck, and as of the hart.